# Back button covers up a previous UIBarButton when pushViewController is called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uibarbuttonitem, pushviewcontroller

My app is navigated by a slide out menu from the left. On top of each `viewController` is a left `UIBarButton` titled "Navigation",  that when touched, opens the slide out menu without having to do the drag effect. I am implementing speech commands into my app, and if a user speaks "Go to Finances", it segues to a `viewController` titled `FianceViewController` through `instantiateViewController` to `pushViewController`.

This all works fine, the only problem is the back button associated with push segue covers up my "Navigation" button in the left slot of the `UINavigationBar`. Using `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` hides both the back button and my "Navigation" button. Is there anyway not make a back button appear when the push happens, but still allow my previously created "Navigation" bar button to be seen and used? Or is there another type of segue that I can do other than `push` if this `UIBarButton` dilemma cannot be solved?

Section of code that segues when spoken:

```
if ([title isEqualToString:@"FINANCES"])
{

    FinanceViewController *fvc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"finance"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding my back button, I figured out I could simply write over it! Using `fvc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;` before `pushViewController`, allows the "navigation" button to override the back button.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the navigation button?
I would try to add it after hiding the back button, something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
UIButton *navigationButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 15.0, 100.0, 32.0)];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:navigationButton];
```

Comment: I have added the code that creates the navigation button. Its tricky because this is declared in a `rootViewController` and not the individual `viewController`s, so let me know what you think.